# Android onDestroy callback

Tags: android

I have activity one that calls activity 2
When user close activitie 2 and gets back to activity 1 i want to do some proccess only when activity 2 onDestroy is finished

I thouht to pass some interface to do a callback from the end of onDestroy

Not sure what is the best way to do it

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom intent with a broadcast receiver
 :[Good Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver_create)

Comment: How does that address the OP's intention?

Comment: He starts the broadcast receiver in the first activity
and lunch the broadcast from the second activity's onDestry method

Comment: Such a BroadcastReceiver would have to be registered with the Application object, in which case it might receive the Intent when no Activity is available, which might not be suitable. Also, how would Activity2's onDestroy() method know for sure that the user pressed the Back button?

Comment: No if a broadcast receiver is registered in the manifest it can receive the broadcast even if it was in the background. and what does the backKey have to do with the question ?

Comment: I said, a background computation _might not be suitable_ -- we just don't know. This is a constraint of your proposed solution. After all, the computation has to be done _after_ onStop(), so it sounds as if there is some synchronization necessary. -- The Back button is implicitly mentioned in the question, because it reads _gets back to activity 1_, not _proceeds to another instance of activity 1_.

Answer (score 0):

The framework doesn't allow having 2 activities in your app running concurrently, so I don't think your idea with an interface sould work.

A simpler alternative that might fit your requirements is to use [StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) in Activity 1 to launch A2. A1 will then get the onActivityResult callback when A2 finishes (for whatever reason)

Look at the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) for details.